# custom form and attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis

In QGIS there is an option to create a `custom form` that should make it easier to create/update attribute entries. So my question here is how is the relation between the two? If I change something in the `attribute table`, does the value in the `custom form` also change and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom form displays the data of the feature. So, if you change the attributes of the feature, the form will also display other values.

Comment: What if I change the data in the form, do the attributes of the feature also change?

Comment: Of course - here is a good post: https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/